# Where to put styled components styles

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, directory-structure

components for styling my react app, so far i had a separate folder in each page's folder called `Styles` and stored my styled component wrappers inside it( e.g. `ThemeToggler.Style.js` or `Section.Style.js` and ... ).

But i realized that my code is getting messy and project files count increases so fast because creating a component means creating 2 files, also some styles was so simple and small that i decided to write them inside the component's main file, because its more readable.

But i still feel that this approach is not good too because some styles are too long to put them inside the component's file , also some styles are not about the component it self, maybe i have a style for showing the adjacent nav of this div if user clicks on it. I thought that i'll put them inside a separate file called `DivOnHover.js` but it seems not correct :)

I'll like to hear your approach for managing styled-components styles, how do you store them in your folder structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Folder Structure would be like this

```
/app
  /pages ( React Router )
  /styles ( CSS only )
  /components ( Reusable Components )
  /styled ( Styled Components )
  /hooks ( React Hooks )
  index.js
  app.js
  routes.js ( React Router )
```

Comment: I'm still not sure about usage of pages folder, should i put page specific components in it ? like components related to Home page ? or its related to something with react-router ?
also , is it good to put all styled component wrapers inside a single folder and dont separate it to page specific components ?

Comment: @TimeRunner2359 Folder Structure may vary from every devs. So Try to make your own and just explore some Public Github Repo of Some Cool React Websites and learn them.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I tend to use this structure pretty often:

```
components/
| Button/
| | Button.js
| | Button.styles.js
| Navbar/
| | Navbar.js
| | Navbar.styles.js
```

At the cost of making more files, it allows you to separate your component logic and styles.